# Unresolved reference: activity_main Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

How to solve this error in MainActivity file. This error occurred after I added > setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
by myself.

```
Unresolved reference: activity_main

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

This is \MainActivity.kt file

```
package com.example.app

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       // Handle the splash screen transition.
         installSplashScreen()
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```